# How to use Blade to append tags

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have Blade view with some dropdowns. Also, I am passing data to this view through my controller.

```
<select name="location">
 <option value="some-value1">Some Label1</option>
 <option value="some-value2">Some Label2</option>
</select>
```

and I have property `$model->location`. How do I append `selected` to the right option? Is it even possible to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a ternary operator in a Blade slot, for example:

```
<option value="value" {{ $model->location == 'value' ? 'selected' : '' }}>Label</option>
```

The `selected` option will only be displayed when your condition (`$model->location == 'value'`) is true

Comment: I didn't want to use if else but I didn't know for this shorthand version. Nice Thanks!